Why does a singularity imply the need for a distribution?
I am following Section 11 of Prof. Etingof's MIT OpenCourseWare notes on "Geometry And Quantum Field Theory" in which he says:

...for $d = 1$, the Green's function $G(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$, for $d > 1$ it is singular at $x = 0$. Namely, $G(x)$ behaves like $C|x|^{2-d}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ for $d > 2$, and as $C\ln|x|$ as $d = 2$. Thus for $d > 1$, unlike the case $d = 1$, the path integral $$\int \phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n) e^{-S(\phi)}D\phi$$ only makes sense if $x_i \neq x_j$. In other words, this path integral should be regarded not as a function but rather as a distribution.

Here $d$ is the dimension.
Why does the singularity of the Green's function imply that the path integral must be interpreted as a distribution?
Please let me know if this question is better suited for math SE.


OP's linked quote mentions that the free massless scalar propagators with Euclidean spacetime signature are singular functions for $d\geq 2$.
These singular functions can be injectively imbedded into the vector space of distributions.
The interpretation in terms of distributions helps consistently resolve singularities in the Euclidean partition function.

Moreover, if we Wick-rotate to Minkowskian spacetime signature, we should include the Feynman $i\epsilon$ prescription. As a result, the propagators become distributions for $d\geq 2$.
Since the propagators are building blocks for the
path integral, the path integral also become a distribution for $d\geq 2$. .



Thank you for your answer.

You have a Gaussian measure with covariance $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle =G(x,y)$. If you were to interpret the random variables $\phi$ as functions, then for each $x$, $\phi(x)$ would be distributed like a Gaussian. But since $\lim_{y\to x}G(x,y)=\infty$ for $d\geq 2$, the variance of such a variable is divergent, contradicting the assumption that it is a Gaussian variable, leading to a contradiction. Thus, $\phi(x)$ cannot be interpreted as a random function, and only $\phi(f)$ for $f$ a test function gives a well defined random variable.

Thank you for your answer. Why must $\phi(x)$ be distributed like a Gaussian?

Because the path integral for the free field is Gaussian! You can see this on an informal level in that the action $S(\phi)$ is a quadratic form in the field. If you think about gaussian-distributed vector $X_i$, then $X_i a_i$ is also gaussian. Similarly here, for every $f$, $\phi(f)$ gives a gaussian random variable with mean zero and variance $C(f,f)  = \int C(x,y)f(x)f(y)dxdy$. You're then taking a sequence of $f_ns\to \delta_{x}$ and checking whether or not this sequence of gaussian variables converges to something reasonable, and it turns out that it does not for $d\geq 2$.

Sorry I'm still a bit confused. The free field is represented as a Gaussian measure $d\phi$ with covariance $C$, which in the context of physics this covariance operator would be determined by the free field propagator. If we interpret $f$ and $g$ as functions then their covariance $C(f,g)$ is equal to $\int fgd\phi$ where the integral is taken over all continuous paths. Why does this imply $f$ or $g$ must also be Gaussian and where is the contradiction that implies $f$ and $g$ must be distributions?

$C(f,g)$ is actually $\int \phi(f)\phi(g)d\phi$. As for the reason $\phi(f)$ has a Gaussian distribution, one can show that a random variable $X$ is Gaussian if and only if $\langle\exp(tX)\rangle = \exp(1/2 \sigma^2 t^2)$. Now, $\langle \exp(t\phi(f))\rangle = \sum_n \frac{t^n}{n!}\langle \phi(f)^n\rangle$. Then, by Wick's theorem, $\langle \phi(f)^n \rangle = 0$ if $n$ is odd, and because there are $(2n-1)!!$ ways to contract $2n$ fields, $\langle \phi(f)^{2n}\rangle = (2n-1)!! C(f,f)^n$. In total you get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n!)} (2n-1!!)C(f,f)^n$.

Breaking up the factorials then finally gives $=\sum_n \frac{t^{2n}}{2^n n!}C(f,f)^n = \exp(\frac{1}{2}t^2 C(f,f))$. The conclusion is that the path integral gives us for each test function $f$ a gaussian random variable $\phi(f)$ with mean zero and variance $C(f,f)$.

Now when $C(x,x)=\infty$, this means that $\phi(x)$, which we would hope to be some random variable representing the value of the field at a point, would have infinite variance, contradicting everything we said so far since there is no gaussian distribution with infinite variance. So these point-like variables do not exist meaningfully.

Thanks a lot this was really helpful! Do you have any recommended reading that goes into this in more depth, especially as it relates to rigorous quantum field theory?

I don't know of a single perfect book, but The P(phi)_2 Euclidean (Quantum) Field theory by Barry Simon and Quantum Physics from a functional integral point of view by Glimm and Jaffe  are both quite good for books on the Euclidean approach

For axiomatic field theory, Bogolyubov's General Principles of Quantum Field theory covers a massive amount of content.

Thanks for the suggestions. I've read parts of the G&J and Simon books and found them a little terse but I suppose there are no alternatives.

Ah yeah unfortunately that just seems to be the nature of the literature in this field.
